# Bluetooth A2DP audio device loses connection when plugged into charger

Tags: audio, bluetooth

I use a UE MEGABOOM Bluetooth speaker with three kinds of devices:

- a Raspberry Pi running OSMC
- my laptop, running Ubuntu MATE 20.04
- my Android phone, running LineageOS 18.1

Mostly I use the speaker with the media center, sometimes with the laptop when traveling, quite seldom with the phone.

A while ago I started noticing that whenever I plug the speaker back into its charger (and only then), it loses the connection. This started happening out of the blue, and was reproducible on the media center every time. It only appears when I plug the speaker into the charger – if I unplug it from the charger while connected, nothing happens.

At some point I tried to reproduce it with the laptop, but here the speaker remained connected when I plugged it in. Recently, however, I noticed the laptop connection dropping as well when I plugged in the speaker. I have not done any thorough tests on the phone yet.

I do not use the app which UE provides for the speaker (I installed it once on a burner device to do the basic configuration, then never used it again).

Theories as to what could be causing this behavior:

1. A new bug in the Linux Bluetooth driver stack, which causes some hiccup when the speaker is connected to the charger: A2DP has some mechanism for reporting the charge status of the device; if the transition from battery power to charging throws the driver off for some reason, that would explain the behavior.
2. Something wrong with the speaker itself. Since OSMC, the device I mainly use the speaker with, experienced this issue much earlier than the laptop, it might have to do with the order in which the devices were connected/paired – or it is not an issue with the speaker at all.

Has anyone experienced similar issues, and/or can help me shed more light in the issue?

Comment: Every single BT audio device I have owned, has always lost connection when it has been plugged in to be recharged.

Comment: Almost certainly not intended behavior (what would the purpose be?), and I am pretty sure it once worked for me (same usage, same devices, just a few updates behind). If an update was at fault, it would have been deployed in Q1/2022.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not sure what causes (or caused) this, but as of mid-May 2022, I am no longer experiencing this issue with the media center (haven’t tried the laptop). When I plug the Megaboom into its charger, the connection to the media center stays up.

If this was due to some bug in the underlying Linux distro, then presumably the fix has been rolled out by now.